# Is this lemma true when N is infinite?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The following lemma is from Stein & Rami, *Real Analysis*. I couldn't find why finite $N$ is necessary here.

> **Lemma 1.1** If a rectangle is the almost disjoint union of finitely many other rectangles, say $R=\bigcup^{N}_{k=1}R_k$, then
> $
> \begin{equation}
> |R|=\sum^{N}_{k=1}|R_k|
> \end{equation}.
> $

Since it's the first chapter, the || represents only the intuitive volume of a rectangle.

Comment: Does $|.|$ represent Lebesgue measure ? If so, then so you are allowed to consider an (countably) infinite sum, indeed.

Comment: I'm guessing that the lemma comes in a point in the development where they don't yet have facts about infinite unions; indeed this lemma could well be used to prove some of those infinite-union facts.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Since it's the first chapter, the || represents only the intuitive volume of a rectangle

Comment: @GregMartin But in the next section, the author uses the compact property of a closed cube( finite subcover) to prove that the exterior measure of a closed cube is equal to its volume. That's why I think if finite here is necessary. Otherwise we don't need to choose finite subcover to get the proof.